# Spring boot app ignores application.yml properties

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

So my new `Spring boot` app seems to ignore properties from the `application.yml` file...

I'm trying to override the default server port by updating the application.yml file to contain

```
server:
  port: 8952
```

But the application starts on port 8080

```
 o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
```

I'm running it from `Intellij`.

application.yml location:

```
C:\myProject\src\main\resources\application.yml
```

Main class location:

```
C:\myProject\src\main\java\com\example\MyApplication.java
```

[image: project structure]

And here is the config window of the app:

[image]

And here are the relevant sections from the pom:

```
 <properties>
    <spring-boot-version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring-boot-version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

It must be a very minor thing that I'm missing here, as in other application of mine it is working as expected

Comment: if you build and run will it be recognized from the jar (just to exclude intellijidea bug)

Comment: Can you show your run configuration in intellij? It is in Run->Edit configurations

Comment: @pepevalbe added

Comment: I call my file "application.properties" and it works to me.

Comment: It seems to be ok.. Have you double checked the yaml file indentation?

Comment: Post your pom dependencies regarding the spring boot? You created the app using initializer? If not, please use spring initializer to create project. That should probably do with depepndecy like spring-boot-starter-web

Comment: @KarthikR added

Comment: remove spring-boot-devtools it ovveriding the tomcat from spring-boot-starter-web that already include a embbed tomcat, i never use devtool if you need that devtool for autoreload feature you need to remove the web stuff

Comment: Try to run your jar from terminal and check on withch port is running !